Keycloak setup for Single SPA angular Project
I'm in the process of developing an application using Single SPA. I've reached the point where I need to integrate Keycloak authentication into my micro frontend architecture.
My question is: Should I integrate Keycloak directly into the Single SPA root configuration or into all the other parcels, and what configurations should I add?
Thank you!
I'm attempting to integrate Keycloak just into the root config, but I'm encountering an issue where the requests coming from the parcels don't include the access token. Additionally, the parcels don't verify the expiration of the token or session.
